Tikz strange behaviour
I use the following code in Tikz :
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a/\n in { 0/i, 60/s, 120/t, 180/3, 240/5, 300/7 } {
        \node[circle, draw] at(\a:2cm) (v\n) {$v_{\n}$};
    }
    \draw (vi) -- (vs);
    \draw (vi) -- (vt);
    \draw (vi) -- (v3);
    \draw (vi) -- (v5);
    \draw (vi) -- (v7);
\end{tikzpicture}

Along a circle, I create 6 nodes which label and name are derived from \n. Then I draw edges between these nodes. All draw works except the last one with the error:
Package pgf Error: No shape named `v7' is known. \draw (vi) -- (v7)
The question is: why? Maybe I missed something...
Thank you for your answer.

Remove the space after '7'.

Tank you so much. Sorry. I have to improve my level in tikz.

Welcome. // Please make it a habit to avoid code snippets, which won‘t and can‘t compile. In doing so, via your preamble, you avoid many comments which would only try to understand, what you are doing and how. Or in other words: we need to know which subset of complexity you picked from Latex. Thank you

I’m voting to close this question because is resolved in the comments
